# How do I trim date in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-format

I have a date variable as `24-dec-08`.
I want only the `08` component from it.

How do I do it in a select statement?

e.g.:

```
select db||sysdate 
--(this is the component where I want only 08 from the date) 
from gct;
```

Comment: select db||to_char(sysdate,'yy') from gct;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `to_char` function this way:

```
to_char(sysdate, 'YY')
```

as [documented here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php).

If you need the integer value, you could use the `extract` function for dates too. Take a look [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php) for a detailed description of the `extract` syntax.

For example:

```
extract(YEAR FROM DATE '2008-12-24')
```

would return *2008*.

If you just need the value of the last two digits, you could apply the [modulo function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/mod.php) `MOD`:

```
mod(extract(YEAR FROM DATE '2008-12-24'), 100)
```

would return *8*.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this in Oracle is:

```
select db||to_char(sysdate,'YY')
from gct;
```

Comment: "to_char(YEAR FROM DATE '2008-12-24', 'YY')" does not work in Oracle.

Comment: Stupid me. I copied some code around and forgot to edit it. Thank you, Tony!